# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in foreach

Tags: php, opencart

Мне нужно, чтобы после создания 5 `li`, создавалось следующее `ul`, и уже в `ul` продолжались создаваться `li`. Только `ul` должны быть все на одном уровне. Вот код, CMS OpenCart.

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?> 
    <div class="children clearfix"> 
        <ul class="children-list children-list-col clearfix"> 
            <?php $k=0; foreach ($children as $child) {(($k%5==0) ?  "</ul><ul>" :"");?> 
                <li> 
                    <a class="link" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" > 
                        <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo $child['thumb']?>" width="40" height="40" alt="" />
                        <span class="text"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></span></a> 
                </li> 
            <?php } ?>                          
        </ul> 
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Возможно есть и другое решение, заранее спасибо!

UPD: При таком коде, выдает ошибку которая написана в заголовке.

```
<?php foreach ($children as $child) {(($k%5==0) ? echo "</ul><ul>" : echo"");?>
```

UPD: На каком-то основании, код `<?php $k=0; foreach ($children as $child) { if($k%5==0) { echo "</ul><ul>"; } $k++;?>`, который проявляет признаки работоспособности, спасибо **tCode**, не совсем работает так как мне надо.. Я уже с этим 2 дня мучаюсь, понятное дело из-за не знания..

```
<div class="children clearfix"> 
                        <ul class="children-list children-list-col clearfix"> 
                            </ul><ul> 
                            <li> 
                                <a class="link" href="http://rumishop2/component/cmp23" > 
                                <img class="thumb" src="http://rumishop2/image/cache/no_image-100x100.png" width="40" height="40" alt="" />
                                <span class="text">Components</span></a> 
                            </li> 

                            <li> 
                                <a class="link" href="http://rumishop2/component/PC123" > 
                                <img class="thumb" src="http://rumishop2/image/cache/no_image-100x100.png" width="40" height="40" alt="" />
                                <span class="text">PC</span></a> 
                            </li> 

                            <li> 
                                <a class="link" href="http://rumishop2/component/mouse" > 
                                <img class="thumb" src="http://rumishop2/image/cache/no_image-100x100.png" width="40" height="40" alt="" />
                                <span class="text">Mice and Trackballs</span></a> 
                            </li> 

                            <li> 
                                <a class="link" href="http://rumishop2/component/monitor" > 
                                <img class="thumb" src="http://rumishop2/image/cache/no_image-100x100.png" width="40" height="40" alt="" />
                                <span class="text">Monitors</span></a> 
                            </li> 

                            <li> 
                                <a class="link" href="http://rumishop2/component/printer" > 
                                <img class="thumb" src="http://rumishop2/image/cache/no_image-100x100.png" width="40" height="40" alt="" />
                                <span class="text">Printers</span></a> 
                            </li> 
                            </ul><ul> 
                            <li> 
                                <a class="link" href="http://rumishop2/component/scanner" > 
                                <img class="thumb" src="http://rumishop2/image/cache/no_image-100x100.png" width="40" height="40" alt="" />
                                <span class="text">Scanners</span></a> 
                            </li> 

                            <li> 
                                <a class="link" href="http://rumishop2/component/web-camera" > 
                                <img class="thumb" src="http://rumishop2/image/cache/no_image-100x100.png" width="40" height="40" alt="" />
                                <span class="text">Web Cameras</span></a> 
                            </li> 

                        </ul> 
                    </div>
```

Это исходник кода Ctrl+U, то бишь... Как здесь видно.. Что код создает юл через каждые 5 ли, но во-первых они не на 1 уровне с `<ul class="children-list children-list-col clearfix">`, а внутри него.. И вдобавок ко всему, ли почему-то все равно создаются в главном юл.
Прошу помочь и помиловать..

Comment: а вы само меню сами верстали ?

Comment: Ну типо того.. Я посмотрел на другом сайте, у них там юл создаются, но это точно не css и не js.

Comment: вы его сверстайте на рабочем столе без php , посмотрите как это будет , а потом уже уже встраивайте php коде но на локальном сервере т.е оптимизируйте на установленном OcStore он же OpenCard

Comment: что, по-вашему, делает вот эта конструкция `(($k%5==0) ?  "</ul><ul>" :"");`?

Comment: Ой, там echo должно стоять.. Я ж Вам объяснил, что мне нужно через каждые пять ли, создавать новое ul

Comment: Все нормально сверстано.. Все ж работает, я ж объясняю, что если ли больше чем 5 штук, то они вылезают за границу блока.. Мне нужно чтобы когда идет 6 раз выполнение цикла, мне создавалось ul и уже в нем создавалось li

Comment: @KirillXiaomi, а теперь почитайте, как работает тернарный оператор (`?:`) в PHP и сами поймете в чем у вас ошибка ;)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, с удовольствием сейчас же прочту

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените:

```
<?php $k=0; foreach ($children as $child) {(($k%5==0) ?  "</ul><ul>" :"");?>
```

На:

```
<?php $k=0; foreach ($children as $child) { if($k%5==0) { echo "</ul><ul>"; } $k++;?>
```

Comment: Не робит.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: Все, исправил.. Пытаюсь добиться сейчас, чего я хочу.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Теперь работает, спасибо..)

Comment: Но не могли бы поправить тот код полностью.. Потому что картина выглядит так..

Comment: На каком-то основании, в самом начале, этот код вызывает <ul>
<div class="children clearfix"> 
   <ul class="children-list children-list-col clearfix"> 
      </ul><ul>